# How to restrict Primefaces inputMask to number and activate the copy and paste

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to restrict `p:inputMask` to numbers only and need to activate copy and paste also, this is my code:

```
<p:inputMask maxlength="18" id="numeroDocumento"
   name="numeroDocumento" label="Número de documento"
   value="#{dtConsultarInfController.numeroDocumento}"
   title="#{pmsg['sif.screen.consultarVerificarInf.label.docNumber']}">
   <p:keyFilter regEx="/[\d]/" />
</p:inputMask>
<p:keyFilter for="numeroDocumento" mask="num" preventPaste="false" />
```

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much my friend, your solution admits the dot sign buy I changed the condition on the onkeypress property and it's working successfull!

This is the solution:

```
<p:inputMask maxlength="18" id="numeroDocumento"
name="numeroDocumento" label="Número de documento"
onkeypress="if((event.which &lt; 48 &amp;&amp; event.which != 8) || event.which &gt; 57) return false;" value="# dtConsultarInfController.numeroDocumento}"     title="#{pmsg['sif.screen.consultarVerificarInf.label.docNumber']}"></p:inputMask><p:keyFilter for="numeroDocumento" mask="num"preventPaste="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added the "onkeypress" to your code, try this now, it will normally restrict typing to numbers only :

```
<p:inputMask maxlength="18" id="numeroDocumento"
 name="numeroDocumento" label="Número de documento"
 <p:inputMask maxlength="18" id="numeroDocumento"
  name="numeroDocumento" label="Número de documento"
    onkeypress="if((event.which &lt; 48 &amp;&amp; event.which != 46 
    &amp;&amp; event.which != 8) || event.which &gt; 57) return false;">
  value="#{dtConsultarInfController.numeroDocumento}"
  title="#{pmsg['sif.screen.consultarVerificarInf.label.docNumber']}">
  <p:keyFilter regEx="/[\d]/" />
</p:inputMask>
<p:keyFilter for="numeroDocumento" mask="num" preventPaste="false" />
  value="#{dtConsultarInfController.numeroDocumento}"
  title="#{pmsg['sif.screen.consultarVerificarInf.label.docNumber']}">
  <p:keyFilter regEx="/[\d]/" />
```